# How to check no records added in last 60 minute in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to perform a check in my query in which i have to perform a count such that no file records are loaded in last 60 min. The file records can be identify by the event time_stamp which is the File_Created_Date column which is from table O2_SDR_HEADER. 
Here is my query in which where condition is missing in which i have to check No files added in table in last 60 minutes:

```
select * 
from O2_SDR_HEADER@FONIC_WHOLESALE OSH 
JOIN O2_SDR@FONIC_WHOLESALE OS ON OSH.ID = OS.O2_SDR_FILE_ID
JOIN sdr_o2@FONIC_RETAIL SO ON SO.ID = OS.ID
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM O2_SDR_HEADER@FONIC_WHOLESALE OSH 
JOIN O2_SDR@FONIC_WHOLESALE OS ON OSH.ID = OS.O2_SDR_FILE_ID
JOIN sdr_o2@FONIC_RETAIL SO ON SO.ID = OS.ID
WHERE OSH.File_Created_Date > sysdate - interval '60' minute
```

Comment: Post that as a separate question

Comment: Ok i have the answer now. Can you please remove the negative vote to my question as i will post my other query in different question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things:

1. Figure out what the time was 60 minutes ago using built in SQL date functions. Put this value in a variable.
2. In your WHERE clause, check whether creation date is <= the time in step 1.

Comment: i want to use just a select statement instead of putting them into variable. Do u knw the query please ?